# How to add package source to ubuntu package list

Tags: packaging

I develop a new open source named [EasyCwmp](http://www.easycwmp.org)  and I want to add it to ubuntu packages list.
how to proceed  ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of paths that a package can take to enter Ubuntu. In most cases, going through Debian first can be the best path. This way ensures that your package will reach the largest number of users as it will be available in not just Debian and Ubuntu but all of their derivatives as well.

Here are some useful links for submitting new packages to Debian:

- [Debian Mentors FAQ](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianMentorsFaq) - debian-mentors is for the mentoring of new and prospective Debian Developers. It is where you can find a sponsor to upload your package to the archive.
- [Work-Needing and Prospective Packages](http://www.debian.org/devel/wnpp/) - Information on how to file “Intent to Package” and “Request for Package” bugs as well as list of open ITPs and RFPs.
- [Debian Developer’s Reference, 5.1. New packages](http://www.debian.org/doc/developers-reference/pkgs.html#newpackage) - The entire document is invaluable for both Ubuntu and Debian packagers. This section documents processes for submitting new packages.

Source: http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html